# Adding an image on a button cause tk to not show anything

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I try to create a chess game in python 3.8.10.
I already set my chess board using Tk in a button grid as follow :

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import ImageTk

#root = str(Path.cwd()) + r"\assets"

window = Tk()
window.title("Jeu d'echec")
window.geometry("560x700")
window.resizable(0,0)

window.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
window.rowconfigure(9, weight = 1)

for i in range(8):
    window.rowconfigure(i+1, weight=2)
    window.columnconfigure(i, weight=2)

squares = []

for i in range(64) :
    squares.append(Button(window, bg = ["white", "black"][(i+i//8)%2], relief="flat", borderwidth=0))
    squares[i].grid(column = i%8, row = 1 + (i//8), sticky="nsew")

#squares[4].config(image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = root + "\WhitePawn.png"))

#Black score label
black_score_label = Label(window, text="Black = 0")

#White score label
white_score_label = Label(window, text="White = 0")

black_score_label.grid(row = 0, columnspan=8)
white_score_label.grid(row = 9, columnspan=8)

window.mainloop()
```

When adding a piece image on a square (removing the #) the GUI appears but is totally white and not clickable.

I think that the script is showing the image but that it is to big. I would love the image to scale to the initial button size but I didn't find a way to do it so that the image would be the good size.

Comment: How big *is* the image? Your idea that it's simply too big is reasonable, but we have no way to test that, not having access to the image.

Comment: The image is big (2048x2048) but the background doesn't match the image color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not saving a reference to the image so it is being destroyed by python's garbage collector. Save the image to a variable to solve this problem.

```
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = root + "\WhitePawn.png")
squares[4].config(image = image)
```

Of course, if you have more than one image you'll need to save each of them. A simple solution is to append them to a list.

```
images = []
...
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = root + "\WhitePawn.png")
squares[4].config(image = image)
images.append(image)
```

Comment: You are right ! Creating the image before referencing it in the button solved the problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you want control over your image size you can first import your image using `PIL` and then add the image to the button:

```
with Image.open(filename) as image:
    og_w, og_h = image.size
    window.update()
    target_width = squares[4].winfo_width()
    new_h = int(target_width * og_h / og_w)
    squares[4].configure(image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(image, size=(target_width, new_h)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I implemented your code in my script and the result is strange : When I launch the sciprt the GUI appears with the empty chess board and 0.5s later the monocolor bug appears.